# Password Protect Specific Shared Folder in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, network-shares, password-protection

how can i password protect a specific shared folder and all the sub-folder/contents in it?

The PC which I want to password protect the folder is running Windows XP. My Workgroup are all using Windows XP except for one Windows 7.

This is an Example

If they open this they will be able to view it:

> \192.168.1.102\Folder Main\

But if they open this folder:

```
\\192.168.1.102\Folder Main\Folder B\
or
\\192.168.1.102\Folder Main\Folder B\<WHATEVER OTHER SUB FOLDER/FILE>
```

if will ask for a Password or Windows Account/Password

I know it can be done for Windows 7 shared folder but i'm not sure about windows XP, Can it be Done?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Right-click that folder, click Properties, go to the Security tab, and add an entry for the users that you want to block access for that denies read access.

Comment: That is for windows 7, I want to do it for windows XP.

Comment: @JeremyJohn: This should work on Windows XP too.  (although I'm not sure about XP Home).  You may need to disable simple sharing in Folder Options.

Comment: There is no Security tab under Properties, just General and Sharing tab. I'm using XP Professional BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Smb not work like that. If you connect to share, it'll connect with permissions of your windows account or with those you'll provide instead. But you can't use multiple account simultaneously to connect to one share.

If you'll connect to \server\share\ and try to acces \server\share\private, then you'll get access denied.

You can however connect explicitely under user you want by Adding a network share drive in "Your comuter" and selecting "login as another user".

Answer (score 0):

You can set Windows Account/Password for a specific shared folder and all the sub-folder/contents in it, but can't set folder password for this, unless you use the third program, such as [kakasoft shared folder protection](http://www.kakasoft.com/password-protect-shared-folder/). It can set folder Password for a specific shared folder inclduing the sub-folder/contents in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (somewhat hackish) method, which consists of the following steps:

1. Enable Advanced Sharing in XP.
2. Create a special user account that will be used only for accessing this one Shared Folder - for example `MyUser`, and give it the necessary permissions. The user account is local to the computer where the Shared Folder is, not to the computer from which you'll be connecting. Also assign a password to that user, for example `MyPassword`.
3. On the computer you'll be connecting from, create a Network Mapped Drive using this command:

   ```
   net use Z: \\192.168.0.101\MySharedFolder MyPassword /user:MyUser
   ```

   Replace `192.168.0.101` with the IP of the computer hosting the shared folder. Note that [you need to use the IP address instead of the hostname](https://superuser.com/a/838703/66282), or it might fail with this error:

   > System error 1219 has occurred.
   >
   > Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user,
   >   using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all
   >   previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.