# Net Use Error 1219 - I just want to mount a network share

Tags: networking, backup, windows-server-2008-r2, net-use

When I log into windows, my system maps a few drives from our server's shares. I have a backup script that I want to run and it maps a few more drives just for the script and then unmaps them when done.

I'm running the following to map:
net use z: "\server\share1" /user:myuser password

It then says System error 1219 has occurred. Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. etc

Thing is, I'm using the same user for everything. Why would it give me this error and how do I fix this? I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 with this script.

Comment: Try using `net use` without parameters, see if it lists any other connection to that server you might need to delete first

Comment: net use reports back all of my shares with all saying status is ok

Comment: I would do a `net use /delete *` and re-run the script to make sure that no other shares were mapped with another user.

Comment: Error 1219 is "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again." Just FYI.

Answer (score 9):

Since at least Windows NT 4.0, only a single set of user credentials can be used for a single server name, where the server name is determined when mapping the resource (e.g. the `server` in `\server\share`).

If using the same set of user credentials is acceptable, the additional server share can be successfully mapped by not specifying the user name or password. So, in your case, performing the first `net use` with the `/user` and `password` arguments and the second without should work.

If using the same set of credentials is not acceptable (i.e. you must map two resources from the same server using different user credentials), you can work around the problem by creating and using a DNS alias for the server, or using the server's IP address.

See the following for additional details:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/the-network-folder-specified-is-currently-mapped/928f6313-fe2c-4d2d-a247-152ec022e062

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938120

Comment: Using the digital IP address worked for me, thanks.  To go back to using own credentials, I deleted the /user: parameter altogether (its spelling using the domain prefix or the email-like suffix seems to matter).

Answer (score 2):

Got it. A quick reboot fixed this issue. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it :)